# how to call kernel terminate event

Tags: php, symfony, events, service, symfony-kernel

Im trying to send response to user and after it make hard work in my service. I found another thread there([How tout use kernel.terminate Event in a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612879/how-tout-use-kernel-terminate-event-in-a-service)). But it doesnt works.When i tried make like in there i got next messages in my logs: php.INFO: User Deprecated: Calling the "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::dispatch()"
So then i tried it like that:

```
public function makeHardWork()
{
    $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function (Event $event){
        $this->logger->log(LogLevel::ERROR,'123456');
    },1);
}
```

Also i tried to dump $kernel in index.php and there is my subscriber.
But nothing logs. What should i do for it works?

Comment: For console and for Web there're different `TERMINATE` events.

Comment: @u_mulder thx for answer, could u please tell what does it mean for me?) im using php-fpm

Comment: Do you expect TERNINATE event when running script via web or via console?

Comment: via web ( after send response)

Comment: And when `makeHardWork` executed?

Comment: @u_mulder from controller

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

services.yaml

```
App\EventListener\SomeEventListener:
    tags:
        - { 'name': 'kernel.event_listener', 'event': 'kernel.terminate', 'method': 'onTerminateEvent' }
```

SomeEventListener

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\TerminateEvent;

class SomeEventListener
{
    private $someSerive;

    public function __construct(SomeService $someService)
    {
        $this->someService = $someService;
    }

    public function onTerminateEvent(TerminateEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ($request->get('_route') !== 'some_route_name') {
            return;
        }

        $this->someService->makeHardWork();
    }
}
```