# Symfony Return Response and then do Heavy Job

Tags: symfony, events, service, dispatch, symfony5

On Symfony 5, I have a controller that calls a service that does a heavy job, it updates rows on the database accordingly to what the user entries.

If user enters a thousand rows I want to `return` a `JsonResponse` to the user and then do the heavy job after and send an email.

I've tried adding this to my service based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612879/how-tout-use-kernel-terminate-event-in-a-service)

```
if($isHeavyJob) {
             $email = $this->request->get("email");
             $this->eventDispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::TERMINATE, function (Event $event) use ($userEmail) {
                    $this->runJob($userEmail);
                });
             return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Is a Heavy Job, wait a response via email.'], 200);
}
$data = $this->runJob();
return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Not a heavy job so here is your data.', 'data' => $data], 200);
```

But i'm getting

```
Uncaught Error: Argument 1 passed to App\Service\HeavyJob::App\Service\HeavyJob{closure}() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event
```

Do I need to create a separate event ?

Comment: You should look into [Symfony Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) and more specifically [async queued messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transports-async-queued-messages). It allows you to send "a message" (a php-object with data in it), e.g. with the data to be changed, and then you can use provided commands to process them in a handler (this is basically where you call your heavy job).

Comment: Remove the `Event` type hint from the callback. you are getting there wrong type.
var_dump it to figure out what is type, is it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you might lose consistency. If you respond to the user and after what do your heavy job, the job might fail and be not completed.
As @dbrumann mention, it better to use [Messaging System](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html). In case of a failure, you could retry your job. If you write code that is tolerated to failer, you could be sure that it will complete successfully.

Comment: yeah I think nginx and php timesout everytime this happens